# React - Difference between two statements with reduxForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have checked sample code of reduxForm with initialized value, the only difference between their code and my code is the following chunk of code..

**My Code** **(Doesn't work with initialValues)**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return{
    initialValues: state.account.data
  };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form:'initializeFromState'
})(connect(mapStateToProps,{load: loadAccount})(InitializeFromStateForm));
```

**Their code** **(Works with InitialValues)** [Taken from here](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/)

```
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState', // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm);

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data, // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }, // bind account loading action creator
)(InitializeFromStateForm);

export default InitializeFromStateForm;
```

I changed their code for connect() and reduxForm with mine, interestingly the initialValues stopped working, now my question is **are both the code different?** if different **what is wrong in my code?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there is a slight difference, you are wrapping the component with `connect` and then with `ReduxForm`, However it should be the other way round

Change your code to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{load: loadAccount})(reduxForm({
  form:'initializeFromState'
})(InitializeFromStateForm));
```

and it should work

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the order in which the react-redux connect HoC, and the redux-form HoC wrap each other.

In your code redux-form wraps the connect HoC, and the `initialValues` are not passed to the form, but to the internal component. The form is initialized with the values, and the internal component (yours) ignores them.

Props flow: redux-form -> connect - **initialValues** -> component

In their code connect wraps redux-form, and the `initialValues` are passed as to the redux-form HoC (the form). The form is initialized with the values.

Props flow: connect - **initialValues** -> redux-form -> component

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. it is helpful.